# Checkbox, PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, status

Quick issue:

I have a checkbox in my code that tells the user if the status of a record is **DONE** or **NOT DONE**. When the user does a records search in the database, the records that show up, show up with the current record status (**DONE** or **NOT DONE**).

If the checkbox is not check means that the record is **NOT DONE**, so I'm trying to place a checkbox on one side of the record status so the user can check it as soon as they are done working on the record. After they check the checkbox, the value is sent to the DB telling the DB that the new status of the record is **DONE**

How can I accomplish this when the following example code: (The results are shown after the user made a search using a form)

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['search']))
{
?>

<?php
}
else
{
    $from = trim($_POST['OLD']);
    $to = trim($_POST['NEW']);
    $status = isset($_POST['Status']) ? "AND status = 'DONE' " :"AND status = 'NOT DONE' ";

    $connection = mysql_pconnect("HOST", "USER", "PASS") or die("Connection failed. ".myslq_error());
    mysql_select_db("DBNAME") or die("Unable to select db. ".mysql_error());
    $query = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE Date >= '$from' AND Date <= '$to' ".$status." ORDER BY date ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "<table class='table' id='SearchResult' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
        echo "<tr class='rowa'><b>";
            echo "<td class='col0 cell'>ID</td>";
            echo "<td class='col1 cell'>Name</td>";
            echo "<td class='col2 cell'>Last Name</td>";
            echo "<td class='col3 cell'>Place</td>";
            echo "<td class='col4 cell'>Station</td>";
            echo "<td class='col5 cell'>Phone</td>";
            echo "<td class='col6 cell'>Date of Record</td>";
            echo "<td class='col7 cell'>Status</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    while($record = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {   
    echo "<table class='table' id='SearchResult' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
        echo "<tr class='rowb'>";
            echo "<td class='col0 cell'>".$record->ID."</td>";
            echo "<td class='col1 cell'>".$record->Name."</td>";
            echo "<td class='col2 cell'>".$record->lastName."</td>";
            echo "<td class='col3 cell'>".$record->Place."</td>";
            echo "<td class='col4 cell'>".$record->Station."</td>";
            echo "<td class='col5 cell'>".$record->Phone."</td>";
            $year_part_of_date = explode('-', $record->date);
            echo "<td class='col6 cell'>".$record->date."</td>";
            echo "<td class='col7 cell'>".$record->Status."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";       
    echo "</table>";
    }   
}
?>
```

---

Thanks everyone for showing me the way :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, like this?

```
echo "<td class='col7 cell'><input type='checkbox' name='status' ".($record->Status == 'DONE' ? 'checked' : '')."/></td>";
```

Comment: Right! :D Now is showing the checkboxes as DONE! Great! Now the thing I'm trying to figure out is the part where the user check those checkboxes to update the Status on the SQL Database.

Is there anyway to work around and do this?

Comment: In the same form you want to implement update? I'd go for AJAX call on checkbox click, but if that is out of your expertise, then you will have to provide a Save button for the user, that will send the form you draw from a database back to the PHP script, to take new parameters and update database records. That's an easy task when you  know how to do it, but certainly not an easy one to write the whole piece of code here.

Comment: Ok thats pretty good for me. I was thinking the same about those 2 options. I think i'll go with providing a save button/form for now. Later i'll update the code to work with AJAX. 

Actually, I already made the form/button to do this, but I got stuck at some point. The thing is that the code I'm using does a search for the records that meet the search specifications, but I'm not sure of how to make the form work for each record status. 

Thanks a lot @Fratyr.